# PHP exclude single quotes around variable in array

Tags: php, arrays, twitter

I am working with the Twitter API and in my application I run the the following query:

```
 $uploaded_media = Twitter::uploadMedia(['media' => $media ]);
```

In the $media variable i have the command which gets the location of the file:

```
$media = 'File::get(public_path(\'/uploads/1.png\'))';
```

The problem i am facing is the query adds single quotes around the $media variable runs like this:

```
 Twitter->query('media/upload', 'POST', array('media' => 'File::get(public_path('/uploads/1.png'))'), true)
```

But when i replace $media with the actual command like this it works fine:

```
 $uploaded_media = Twitter::uploadMedia(['media' => File::get(public_path('/tw-uploads/1.png')) ]);
```

How can i exclude the single quotes around the $media variable when i run the first query which i believe to be the problem.

This is the Twitter API for Laravel that I'm using in my application: https://github.com/thujohn/twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you setting up the variable like this:
`$media = 'File::get(public_path(\'/uploads/1.png\'))';` ?

Shouldn't you just do:
`$media = File::get(public_path('/uploads/1.png'));`

Here's an example of a route from their github with your code:
`Route::get('/', function() {
        $media = $media = File::get(public_path('/uploads/1.png'));
        $uploaded_media = Twitter::uploadMedia(['media' => $media)]);
        return Twitter::postTweet(['status' => 'Laravel is beautiful', 'media_ids' => $uploaded_media->media_id_string]);
});`

Comment: Wow, I didn't even realize i was wrapping it around with double quotes until i read over this. Completely ignored it. Sorry, i need some sleep. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would it work if you removed the single quotes from the `$media`?

```php
$media = File::get(public_path(\'/uploads/1.png\'));
```

Alternatively you could create a function.

Comment: He was calling a function inside of ' ', when that is not going to do nothing more than treat it as a string.